# jquery each not working properly

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am trying to loop through a set and try to set a global variable in loop. For some reason the loop executes after other code has finished execution.

Sample

Declared outside of ready function is

```
var lt1,lt2;
```

The Loop

```
lt1="opp";
$('#map_block').gmap().bind('init', function(ev, map) {
    $.each(places,function(i, val) {
        lt2 = val['h_longitude'];   
        lt1 = (val['h_latitude']);
        clientPosition1 = new google.maps.LatLng(val['h_latitude'], val['h_longitude']);  
        console.log(lt1);
        $('#map_block').gmap('addMarker', {'position': clientPosition1 , 'bounds': false, 'icon':hicon }).click(function() {$('#map_block'). gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content':' Test'});
    });
});
console.log(lt1);
```

The consoles shows as below

```
opp
41.222
42.4455
43.5566
```

It seems loop executes after the code execution last `console.log(lt1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the map loads asynchronously. "When the map is fully initialized (with bounds) it will trigger the 'init' event." [source](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/jquery_ui_map_v_3_sample_code)

As a result, your first output is the bottom console.log which results in `opp`. At a later time, the map is loaded, and the init event is fired executing the callback anonymous function. That function iterates using the defined `each` loop and outputs its results. This is why you are seeing that order of events transpiring.

If you need code to execute after init, consider executing that code in a function which is invoked in the callback of init.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I tried following callback but it did not worked ( I mean call back) `$('#map_block').gmap({'callback': function() {  console.log(lt1);   }`